# Why does firefox say "connection partially encrypted" on this page?

Tags: asp.net, html, firefox, ssl, google-chrome

Here's the page:

https://www.testmasters.net/test/ssltest2.aspx

When I go to it (in firefox or chrome), it says "connection partially encrypted". But all references to objects are https and not http as far as I can tell.

What's odd is that if you remove the RequiredFieldValidator, the page works fine. Here's the source (ASP.NET 3.5):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>SSL Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        SSL Test #1
        <asp:TextBox runat='server' ID='textDude' />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat='server' ID='requiredDude' ControlToValidate='textDude'
            Display='Dynamic' />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question. WebResource.axd was not only going over http and not https.